# Symfony2 Searching Database with Select2 and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, doctrine

My FAQ System is working well, but I want to include a search function with Select2.

What I got so far:

**Select2 AJAX Script**

```
    <script>
    $("#searchall").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "/ajax/searchallSelect2",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
                // scrolling can be used
                params.page = params.page || 1;

                return {
                    results: data.items,
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1,
    });
```

**AjaxController.php**

```
    /**
 * @Route("/ajax/searchallSelect2", name="ajax_searchall_select2")
 */
public function searchallSelect2Action(Request $request)
{
    dump($request);
    exit;
    return $this->render('', array('name' => $name));
}
```

**Select2 Form in "index.html.twig"**

```
    <select id='searchall' style="width: 300px">
</select>
```

Firebug console output after typing in the select2 search field:

**GET http://localhost:8000/ajax/searchallSelect2?q=test 200 OK 16ms**

My question is, how do I implement the database searching? Simply with getRepository in the AjaxController?

```
        $allfaqs = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Faq')
        ->findAll();
```

Or do I need to search the database in the Ajax script?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its up to you to write the `queryBuilder` in controller or in `repository` (Recommended) and call that in the controller. You shouldn't call `->findAll()` in your repository as it will get you all data which you don't need. You need to filter data as per your request query parameter coming from ajax i.e. `?q=test`. Below is a code snippet for your Controller.

**In your controller :**

```
/**
 * @Route("/ajax/searchallSelect2", name="ajax_searchall_select2")
 */
public function searchallSelect2Action(Request $request)
{
    $key = $request->query->get('q'); 

    // Find rows matching with keyword $key..

    $allfaqs = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Faq')->filterByKey($key);

    // customize your output as per Select2 requirement..
    return new JsonResponse($allfaqs);
}
```

**In your Repository :** (Considering you search against a 'name' property in FAQ.)

```
/**
 * @param string $key
 *
 * @return type
 */
public function filterByKey($key)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('faq')
        ->andWhere('faq.name LIKE :key')
        ->setParameter('key', '%' . $key . '%')
        ->getQuery();

    return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

Hope it helps! Let me know your concerns otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I solved it 10 minutes ago, but I appreciate your help.

My Select2 is searching now for the FAQ Question, Answer and the Tags that are linked with the Faq (ManyToMany).

Working well.

Maybe someone will need this:

```
   /**
 * @Route("/ajax/searchallSelect2", name="ajax_searchall_select2")
 */
public function searchallSelect2Action(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT c
        FROM AppBundle:Faq c WHERE c.question LIKE \'%'.$request->get('q').'%\' OR c.answer LIKE \'%'.$request->get('q').'%\'');

    $query2 = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT c
        FROM AppBundle:Tag c WHERE c.name LIKE \'%'.$request->get('q').'%\'');
    $faqs = $query->getResult();
    $tmpTags = $query2->getResult();
    $returnArray = [];
    $tmpReturns = array();
    foreach($faqs as $faq) {
        $tmpReturns[$faq->getId()] = $faq;
    }
    foreach($tmpTags as $tmpTag) {
        foreach($tmpTag->getFaqs() as $tmpFaq) {
            if(!isset($tmpReturns[$tmpFaq->getId()])) {
                $tmpReturns[$tmpFaq->getId()] = $tmpFaq;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($tmpReturns as $faq)
    {
        /** @var $faq Faq */
        $tags = array();
        foreach($faq->getTags() as $tag) {
            /** @var $tag Tag */
            $tags[] = $tag->getName();
        }
        $returnArray[] = array(
            'id' => $faq->getId(),
            'text' => 'Titel => '. $faq->getQuestion(). ' '
                . 'Inhalt: '. $faq->getAnswer(). ' '
                . '('.implode(', ', $tags).')'
        );
    }

    return new JsonResponse($returnArray);
}
```